# Finding smallest a+b from given conditions.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm stuck on a decade old olympiad problem which is as follow:

**Find least possible value of a+b where a,b are positive integers such that 11 divides a+13b and 13 divides a+11b.**

I m clueless. I tried something like a+11b=13k and a+13b=11m (for some positive integer k and m), but that didn't work.

Hoping for help,I shall be thankful if you give an easy answer with a bit of explaination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

we have

$a+13b \equiv 0 \mod 11$,
$a+11b \equiv 0 \mod 13$

$\implies$

$a+2b \equiv 0 \mod 11$,
$a-2b \equiv 0 \mod 13$

$\implies$

$2a =11p + 13q$ and $4b=11p-13q$.

thus

$a=23$ and $b=5$ with $p=3,q=1$.

Comment: how did you conclude that $a=23$ and $b=5$ ? By guessing?